# ffprobe - getting file info from pipe

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

I've got an oog file (it was mixed by sox from two audiostreams recorded by pbx Asterisk) and I'm trying to get file information with ffprobe.
When I use something like

```
cat %filename%.ogg | ffprobe -i -
```

I get invalid file info (Duration : N/A,  wrong bitrate and etc.)
When I try

```
ffprobe -i %filename%
```

Everything works fine and I get file info.
What could be wrong? File content?

Comment: I know its over 4 years later but I was trying to recently do something similar and you [can't](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4358). Most formats need to read the whole file to work out the duration, which is why specifying the direct filename works because it has access to that - and ffprobe would need to be changed ! Very annoying! You can do something with `ffmpeg` but it would mean reading the whole file: `ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -f null /dev/null < inputfile.mp4`

Comment: I just got hit by this. Why did they close the ticket on `ffmpeg`?

Answer (score 5):

Just a quick note to say that piping input to `ffprobe` seems to work just fine. Use a hyphen in place of the input file and you are off to the races. Here is an example with a random video file on my system:

```
cat 01.mp4 | ffprobe -show_format -pretty -loglevel quiet -
```

Returns:

```
[FORMAT]
filename=pipe:
nb_streams=2
nb_programs=0
format_name=mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2
format_long_name=QuickTime / MOV
start_time=N/A
duration=0:02:56.400000
size=N/A
bit_rate=N/A
probe_score=100
TAG:major_brand=isom
TAG:minor_version=512
TAG:compatible_brands=isomiso2mp41
TAG:creation_time=1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
TAG:title=yy.mp4
TAG:encoder=Lavf52.78.3
[/FORMAT]
```

Comment: `bit_rate` is absent if input is a pipe and present if input is a file. any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 3):

As of version 1.0.7 of ffprobe you can even get the output in a JSON formatted output:

> ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format Ramp\ -\ Apathy.mp3

Which produces the follwing output:

```
{
    "format": {
        "filename": "Ramp - Apathy.mp3",
        "nb_streams": 2,
        "format_name": "mp3",
        "format_long_name": "MP2/3 (MPEG audio layer 2/3)",
        "start_time": "0.000000",
        "duration": "203.638856",
        "size": "4072777",
        "bit_rate": "159999",
        "tags": {
            "title": "Apathy",
            "artist": "Ramp",
            "album": "Evolution Devolution Revolution",
            "date": "1999",
            "genre": "Metal"
        }
    }
}
```

I think you can get the probe using cat, do you have any requirement to cat the file contents? If not just use ffprobe  without cat.

Comment: He specifically asks for input *from pipe* - not a file! Thanks, but is useless, he said he had the duration with file input...

Comment: This is the answer to the other question. Question: "how to read from pipe", answer: "you can use JSON format", strange, isn't it? I've checked the history of edits - question didn't change. (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13763047/revisions)

Comment: I can't send the nicely formatted json to another file using either stdout `1>` or stderr `2>`.  `-o output.file.json` is rejected as an unknown option.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

And you can pipeline it from remote site by `curl`

```
curl  --silent --header "Range: bytes=0-51200" https://example.com/your.mp4 | ffprobe -v quiet -show_format -of flat=s=_ -show_entries stream=height,width,nb_frames,duration,codec_name -
```